# Create and update JSON file using stored procedure

Tags: php, json, codeigniter-3

I want to create a JSON file using stored procedure and update that jsonfile when my table data get changed. I don't know how to do. Please can anyone help me to sort that issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $someNewData = array("foo"=>"bar"); //example
    if(!file_exists("./data.json")) {
      $file = fopen('data.json', 'w');
      fwrite($file, '');
      fclose($file);
    }

   $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents("./data.json"), true);
   if(!is_array($jsonData)){$jsonData=array();}
   if(isset($someNewData) && is_array($someNewData)){
      file_put_contents("./data.json", json_encode(array_merge($someNewData, $jsonData)));
   }
```

I hope that helps you :)

Comment: your code is correct. But I want to update that json file when my table data changes not everytime.